# Google Assistant ignores FanSpeed, Toggles traits on Thermostat

Tags: actions-on-google

I have a thermostat, which has capabilities of

1. Setting temperature. Works through Home app.
2. Setting thermostat mode. Works through Home app.
3. Setting fan speed. Does not work. Google Assistant ignores setting the fan speed and just shows results from regular Google search
4. Setting horizontal swing toggle. Google Assistant ignores it, same as above.

According to https://developers.google.com/actions/smarthome/tools/validator/ my Sync response should be correct. Below is an example of my sync response.

```
{"requestId":"ff36a3cc-ec34-11e6-b1a0-64510650abcf","payload":{"agentUserId":"1","devices":[{"id":"1","type":"action.devices.types.THERMOSTAT","traits":["action.devices.traits.TemperatureSetting","action.devices.traits.FanSpeed","action.devices.traits.Toggles","action.devices.traits.OnOff"],"name":{"defaultNames":["Controller"],"name":"Controller","nicknames":["Controller"]},"roomHint":"livingRoom","deviceInfo":{"manufacturer":"Airpatrol","model":"Wifi","hwVersion":"1","swVersion":"1"},"attributes":{"availableThermostatModes":"off,heat,cool,on,dry,auto,eco","thermostatTemperatureUnit":"C","commandOnlyTemperatureSetting":false,"availableFanSpeeds":{"speeds":[{"speed_name":"auto","speed_values":[{"speed_synonym":["auto"],"lang":"en"}]},{"speed_name":"min","speed_values":[{"speed_synonym":["min"],"lang":"en"}]},{"speed_name":"norm","speed_values":[{"speed_synonym":["norm"],"lang":"en"}]},{"speed_name":"max","speed_values":[{"speed_synonym":["max"],"lang":"en"}]}],"ordered":true},"availableToggles":[{"name":"swingHorizontal","name_values":[{"name_synonym":["horizontal-swing"],"lang":"en"}]}],"reversible":true},"willReportState":true},{"id":"432423","type":"action.devices.types.THERMOSTAT","traits":["action.devices.traits.TemperatureSetting","action.devices.traits.FanSpeed","action.devices.traits.Toggles","action.devices.traits.OnOff"],"name":{"defaultNames":["Another controller"],"name":"Another controller","nicknames":["Another controller"]},"roomHint":"livingRoom","deviceInfo":{"manufacturer":"Secret","model":"Secret","hwVersion":"1","swVersion":"1"},"attributes":{"availableThermostatModes":"off,heat,cool,on,dry,auto,eco","thermostatTemperatureUnit":"C","commandOnlyTemperatureSetting":false,"availableFanSpeeds":{"speeds":[{"speed_name":"auto","speed_values":[{"speed_synonym":["auto"],"lang":"en"}]},{"speed_name":"min","speed_values":[{"speed_synonym":["min"],"lang":"en"}]},{"speed_name":"norm","speed_values":[{"speed_synonym":["norm"],"lang":"en"}]},{"speed_name":"max","speed_values":[{"speed_synonym":["max"],"lang":"en"}]}],"ordered":true},"availableToggles":[{"name":"swingHorizontal","name_values":[{"name_synonym":["horizontal-swing"],"lang":"en"}]}],"reversible":true},"willReportState":true}]}}
```

Why is it not working and what can I do about it? I also tried using AC_UNIT, but FanSpeed and Toggles still do not seem to have any effect.

Comment: "Turn on the controller horizontal swing" seemed to work, as did "Set the controller fan speed to max".

Comment: How did you test it?

Comment: Issue was for me that I was using location/group name like "living room" instead of device name. Although temperature and mode worked with "living room".

Comment: I copied your SYNC response to create a virtual copy using the sample project. Then I was able to make the queries above.

Comment: Seems like it makes sense for one to want to adjust the temperature of a room, but rooms don't have a fan or horizontal swing directly, so you'd want to defer to the device-level setting.